# Error while installing eclipse for J2EE Developers?

Tags: eclipse

I'm getting the following error while extracting the eclipse-jee-indigo-SR2-linux-gtk-x86_64.tar.gz file.Here is the error msg.

Error Message:

```
 gzip: stdin: unexpected end of file
 tar: Unexpected EOF in archive
 tar: Unexpected EOF in archive
 tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
```

Comment: harikrishna , aa file sarigga download avvaledu. marala download chey.

Comment: I even checked the size of file..

Comment: adi corrupt ayyindhi . size equal unna no confirm about quality.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently you have downloaded an incomplete archive. Retry the download (possibly with different mirror) or use [Ubuntu package](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/eclipse-platform/).